# How to use GROUP BY together with HAVING?

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I'm trying to select all ips from my database that has visited my website, more than once, at least a day apart, from this month, but my sql query is showing an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT ip,COUNT(ip) AS matches
FROM ipAll
WHERE DATE LIKE  '%-12-%'
HAVING matches > '1'
GROUP BY ip
```

**Error:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY ip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HAVING` comes after `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(ip) AS matches
FROM ipAll
WHERE DATE LIKE  '%-12-%'
GROUP BY ip
HAVING matches > 1;
```

However, you should write the query more like this:

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(ip) AS matches
FROM ipAll
WHERE MONTH(DATE) = 12
GROUP BY ip
HAVING matches > 1;
```

Do not use `LIKE` on dates, because the date is converted to a string (implicitly) using local internationalization settings.  These could change and just break the code.  Also, do not use string constants where you want a number.

Comment: date is actually a column name

Comment: @frosty . . . I miss the point of your comment.  MySQL allows `DATE` as a column name.  I might not approve of it (because it is also a type and a function name so it should be reserved, in my opinion), but it is allowed.  If `date` is stored as a string, then you need to learn better naming conventions.  It should be stored as a date or called something like `datestr`.

Comment: I guess I was just confused, but I think I understand now, after rereading your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because according to mysql documentation having clause must be after group by clause not before.

So your query must look like this

```
SELECT ip,COUNT(ip) AS matches FROM ipAll WHERE DATE LIKE  '%-12-%' GROUP BY ip HAVING matches > '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(ip) AS matches
FROM ipAll
WHERE DATE LIKE  '%-12-%'
GROUP BY ip
HAVING matches > 1;
```