# MySql Query problem Unexpected ordering of clauses. (near "having" at position 117)

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I have to convert all of my SQL queries to MySql for my University Project, but i've ran into a problem with the query below:

```
select a.actor_name, count(fa.actor_id) as Movies
from Actor a
    join Film_Actor fa on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
having count(fa.actor_id) = (select distinct max(count(actor_id)) from Film_Actor group by actor_id)
group by a.actor_name;
```

It say's:

> Unexpected ordering of clauses. (near "having" at position 117)

I'm sure i have a syntax problem in the MySql code (we were taught no MySql only Sql)

Comment: `having` comes after `group by`, not before it

Comment: And even then the having criteria is going to error, the subquery must return a single value. Should this just return 1 row ordered by the count descending?

Comment: @Stu yes, it should, but i thought the `max()` will handle to return only one row.

Comment: Except you have a group by in the sub query, so it will return a row for each `actor_id` - have you run it in isolation? You don't need distinct with a group by since each row is already distinct; order by the count descending limit 1.

Comment: It may help to see the original query and what you've attempted.  Maybe you're after a cross apply/lateral or something else... What's the query trying to do?  Return the actor(s) in the most movies?  but then why the group by in the subquery?  ... so what is it you're really after?)  A minimally complete verifiable example   sample data using existing query along with results; and expected results in new system.

Comment: @xQbert  yes it should display all of the actors who played in the most movies, the original query was just like the query above, and it worked in `sql`, although i see now the `distinct` keyword was unnecessary.

Comment: you can't next aggregrates like that.  `select distinct max(count(actor_id)) from Film_Actor group by actor_id)` by itself would throw an error.  I think you just want to get rid of the max and distinct and order by the count descending and limit to 1 result.  so... `select count(actor_id) from Film_Actor group by actor_id order by count(actor_Id) desc Limit 1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY together with HAVING?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193515/how-to-use-group-by-together-with-having)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can not nest aggregate functions in such a manner.  Try this instead: We use the subquery, order by the count, and limit results to just 1 record to get the "most" movie's an actor has been in.

```
SELECT a.actor_name, count(fa.actor_id) as Movies
FROM Actor a
INNER JOIN  Film_Actor fa on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
HAVING count(fa.actor_id) = (SELECT count(actor_id) 
                             FROM Film_Actor 
                             GROUP BY actor_id 
                             ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
                             LIMIT 1)
GROUP BYa.actor_name;
```

Partial Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c511932c7a16f8c9f5ecb85f03ee21cb